# VS2015 hangs on ionic install via nuget

Tags: cordova, nuget, ionic-framework, windows-10

I'm adding ionic and it's dependencies to a new blank cordova app in VS2015, in Win 10 pro, in parallels on a mac. Nuget is getting through what looks like most of the AngularJS plumbing then freezes and CPU skyrockets for VS. Is this a common issue when installing ionic in this setup? Should I use NPM instead of Nuget?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the answer to my problem was to leave Microsoft campus (-_-). It failed five times from EBC and worked a charm at home.

Comment: I'm having this same issue, and I'm not on the Microsoft campus

Comment: Yeah it just started working after a bit. One of those things.

Comment: so as an experiment I should just let it run while I'm away doing other things, see if it works?

Comment: naw I'd say you'd have a better bet restarting the job from a different location. Basically what happened for me was (at MS of all places) it wasn't working. Came home, did it from here, worked. Deleted solution, went back to same location at MS, added to new solution, worked fine. Go figure. Are you behind any proxy that may need configuring?

Comment: I would run ionic from nuget on a TypeScript Cordova project. After letting it sit for a while, the UI became responsive again, but the Output window still looked frozen, but once I let it autohide, then refocused, it was updated. I can replicate that behavior 100% of the time. Maybe it's something with Ionic's NuGet package. Don't know.